# Not able to execute sort command using Runtime or ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, shell, command-prompt

I am trying to execute this command `sort --field-separator="," --key=2 /home/dummy/Desktop/sample.csv" -o /home/dummy/Desktop/sample_temp.csv` using Java `Runtime` and `ProcessBuilder`.

Manually I am able to execute this command in linux, but using `Runtime` or `ProcessBuilder`, this command does not execute. It returns with an `error code = 2`.

Edit:

If I am trying to execute 'ls' command in linux through Java, I get the list of files in the current directory. But, If I try to execute the command 'ls | grep a', an IOException is thrown with error code=2.
Here is the snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    InputStream is = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls | grep a");
    try {
        Process prs = pb.start();
        is = prs.getInputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        int size = 0;
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while((size = is.read(b)) != -1){
            baos.write(b, 0, size);
        }
        System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray()));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally
    {
        try {
            if(is != null) is.close();
            if(baos != null) baos.close();
        } catch (Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Error code 2, had you search for it, means that the command can not be found

Comment: @MadProgrammer But I am able to execute that manually. And error code 2 means Misuse of Shell BuiltIns

Comment: What OS?  What is `sort`?  Normally `2` means file not found on most OS when trying to execute a command

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In my experience with ProcessBuilder on Windows to run bulit in commands (PATH) I had to invoke CMD.EXE /C <command> or I would get the same error. However the OP appears to be running Unix/Linux.

Comment: I second @DavidPostill: please post Java code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a range of issue with your code. Hence you did not supply your code I can only guess.

1. The output file needs to be already created
2. The ',' field separator does not need the quotes around it (see code below)

So after these 2 issues (both making the program exit with '2'), this code actually works:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList("sort", "--field-separator=,", "--key=2", "/tmp/sample.csv", "-o",
                "/tmp/sample_temp.csv"));
        Process p = pb.start();
        int returnCode = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println(returnCode);
    }

}
```

Will print '0' and will sort the file correctly.

For the 'ls | grep' issue, read this great article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-javahen-runtime-exec---won-t/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

The article basically explains that the Runtime.exec (and the ProcessBuilder wrapper) is for running processes and not a Shell (the ls | grep you are trying are actually 2 processes in Linux communicating with each other thru stdout/in).

Comment: Nopes.. Please run your code. It returns the error code which is 2. I have attached the answer. Please find it.

Comment: No, I works like a charm! Have you got both files in the /tmp directory (note that I have changes the location of the files just to test it on my PC)? What you did is an unnecessary workaround. Please re-run my code, I guarantee it works and is what you need.

Comment: Thanks man !! It works like a charm .. Earlier, I did not change the file path.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to execute that manually. And error code 2 means Misuse of Shell BuiltIns

I see in your example you are only invoking "ls", not "/usr/bin/ls" (or something like that).

When you execute manually you have the luxury of `PATH` environment variable which is not availabled to the process you create.

Use "`which ls`" to discover the location of 'ls' on your target system. For your code to be portable you will have to make it a configurable option.

Comment: This is generally true for other commands, but ls and cd specifically are built into the shell and are not available in /usr/bin or anywhere else for that matter.

Comment: Are you sure about that? At least in my system there is a binary called `/bin/ls`. I had a look here and it doesn't list `ls` as one of the shell builtins ... http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bash-shell-list-all-builtin-commands/ - in fact his page gives a command you can use to test this: `type -a ls`

Answer (score 0):

this is the way to execute any bash commands like sort, ls, cat (with sub-options). Please find the snippet:

```
private String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("script.sh");
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}
```

In the exec() method, I passed a shell script which contains the bash command within it. That linux command will be executed and you can carry on with the next task. Hope this was helpful.